# Help with install on a non working windows compter

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, downloads

How do I install Ubuntu on a non working windows computer?? As In my windows wont start cause it says its a illegal copy and boots down before I can install Ubuntu...

Comment: You should be able to start up from the live DVD/USB with Ubuntu. If that is impossible, change the bios settings for boot up devices/priority. (many times by pressing **Esc** or **F2**. Before the OS loads, you should be able to see how to enter the bios settings.

Comment: Thanks Jacob , Ive tried that mabey Im not doing it right but I will try again... im guessing In bios I change to boot from Usb or dvd and not sata

Comment: Nono, not sata, but on boot up, a message flashes to say how to enter bios settings. Sometimes you have to be really concentrated to be able to read :).

Comment: "im guessing In bios I change to boot from Usb or dvd and not sata" -> did you manage to get into the BIOS menu already?

Answer (score 0):

Check some pages

- http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/bios_manufacturer.htm
- http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_mb.htm
- $SEARCH_ENGINE search for `bios keys` or similar

and check the different key combinations (a lot more than <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> (although there're the most popular)). If you don't know your mainboard manufacturer and/or type, try some of them. Either get into the BIOS menu or into the boot device menu and choose `USB`, if there're multiple entries try all of them. The entry succeeded if the Ubuntu live session boots, if failed if the old system boots.